# How to automate creation of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a task to create several img-elements and add for them a src, that will be immediately displayed.
I wrote this:

```
var mass_id = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {  
    var td = document.createElement('img');
    td.id = 'img'+i;
    td.src = links[i];
    mass_id.push(td);
    document.getElementById(td.id).src = links[i];
}
```

`links` is array of links to images.

But without adding in the begining `<img id='img0'/>` , i'm getting an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"

So how can I fix that with avoiding `<img id='img0'/>`?

Comment: Are trying to append the images into a container? Maybe a div?

Comment: You can't use `document.getElementById` on elements that are not appended to the document yet!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Not even close to that question!

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no sense. You already have a reference for the element, why are you trying to select it? It hasn't been appended to the DOM yet, so your selection will return null. You've already set the `src` attribute two lines above that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
document.getElementById(td.id).src = links[i];
```

You're trying to retrieve the element that you have just created from the DOM, but you did not add it to the DOM in the first place. Additionally, there is no need to set `src` attribute twice. You need to add your virtual element into DOM, as such:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(td);
```

Consider following working snippet.

```js
var mass_id = new Array();
var links = ["http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/?1", "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/?2"]
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {  
var td = document.createElement('img');
td.id = 'img'+i;
td.src = links[i];
mass_id.push(td);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(td);
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```